# Image push/pull very slow with OpenShift Origin 3.11

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, okd

I'm setting up an OKD Cluster in a VM via `oc cluster up`. My VM has 6 GB of RAM and 2 CPUs. Interactions with the internal image registry are very, very slow (multiple minutes to pull or push an image, e.g. when building an application via S2I). At the same time, htop shows me a CPU utilization of 100% for both CPUs within the VM. Is there any way to avoid this issue?

Comment: It seems your system or network environment has problem, you can separate this issue into bits and pieces as confirming the same work in other system.

Comment: I think I got around to understanding what's happening. I was using a custom S2I image with a huge pre-baked Maven repo. And I were using incremental builds, causing the entire repo to be added each time I started a build of that app. So images got huge (multiple GB), causing the CPU usage when pushing them.